# What is the difference between %u & %g?

Tags: java, api, logging

What is the difference between %u & %g  (Log File Pattern Variables) in Java Logging API and when they are used?

Thanks

Comment: yes, in %g what should i specify?, should it be specified automatically starting from zero? hence we turn the flag for rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution from FileHandler API

> If no "%g" field has been specified and the file count is greater than
>   one, then the generation number will be added to the end of the
>   generated filename, after a dot.
>
> Thus for example a pattern of "%t/java%g.log" with a count of 2 would
>   typically cause log files to be written on Solaris to
>   /var/tmp/java0.log and /var/tmp/java1.log whereas on Windows 95 they
>   would be typically written to to C:\TEMP\java0.log and
>   C:\TEMP\java1.log
>
> Generation numbers follow the sequence 0, 1, 2, etc.

while %u make the file name unique if multiple apps trying to log to the same app.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern consists of a string that includes the following special components that will be replaced at runtime:

```
"/" the local pathname separator
"%t" the system temporary directory
"%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
"%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
"%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
"%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
```